# Splitting a String with a Regular Expression

Tags: android, string

I'm trying to split a string with a regular expression.  But it is not working, the content is going all to the first array position of the string array.  Isn't this correct?:

scanResult is not relevant, just a simple string.

```
StringBuffer scanList = new StringBuffer();
for cycle{
    scanList.append("SPl"+scanResult.SSID+"ID:"+scanResult.BSSID);
}
String result=scanList.toString();
String[] actual=result.split("SP1");
```

Answer (score 1):

"SPl" is not the same as "SP1".  You are using a lower-case L in the first String and the number 1 in the second string.

I would also update you append String to append all the values.  It is usually better to do something similar to the following:

```
sb.append(val1).append(val2).append(val3).append(val4);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in your `append`, you have `SPl` (S-P-lowercase l) and in the `split`, you have `SP1` (S-P-One)